# Does not work <h:outputText> in <p:panelGrid>?

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, seam

When I use `<h:outputText>` in `<p:panelGrid>`, getter property, `getStartDate()` and `getEndDate()` does not work. But, When I remove `<p:panelGrid>` from page, `getter` property is work well. One more things, when I click `Go To Next Week` link, I get null value of `endDate` in `nextWeek()` action method. I don't why, even I use `DatePick` as `Conversation Scope`.

mypage.xhtml

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p:commandLink action="#{DatePick.nextWeek()}" immediate="true" value="Go To Next Week" />          
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <p:panelGrid style="margin-top:-1px;" id="datePanel">
                    <h:outputText value="#{DatePick.startDate}" style="color:#333333;font-size:15px;">
                        <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                    </h:outputText>
                    -
                    <h:outputText value="#{DatePick.endDate}" style="color:#333333;font-size:15px;">
                        <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                    </h:outputText>
            </p:panelGrid>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

DatePick.java

```
@Name("DatePick")
@Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
public class DatePick {
    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;
    private boolean initFlag = true;

    public void init() {
        System.out.println("init().....");
        initFlag = false;
        startDate = new Date();
    }

    public boolean getInitFlag() {
        System.out.println("getInitFlag() : " + initFlag);
        return initFlag;
    }

    public Date getEndDate() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();        
        cal.setTime(startDate);
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 7); 
        endDate =  cal.getTime();
        System.out.println("getEndDate() : " + endDate);
        return endDate;
    }

    public Date getStartDate() {
        System.out.println("getStartDate() : " + startDate);
        return startDate;            
    }

    public void nextWeek() {
        System.out.println("nextWeek() : " + endDate);
        startDate = endDate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the `columns` attribute. Without that, it defaults to 0 columns and you'd need to use `<p:row>` and `<p:column>` explicitly. See also [the `<p:panelGrid>` showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panelGrid.jsf).

Your concrete functional requirement is unclear, but perhaps you want to achieve this 1-column layout?

```html
<p:panelGrid columns="1">
    <h:outputText ... />
    <h:outputText ... />
</p:panelGrid>
```

Or perhaps you *just* want to display them below each other? The whole thing is inside a plain HTML `<table>` already and using a `<p:panelGrid>` for that makes visually very little sense. Just use a `<br>` then.

```html
<h:outputText ... />
<br />
<h:outputText ... />
```